# Value of variable changing before function is finished running

Tags: php

I have an image uploading script in which i use the following setup to assign names to uploaded images;

```
        $saltdate = date( 'U' );
        $saltuser = $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR];
        $saltname = md5($saltdate.$saltuser);

// Recieve, Process, Save uploaded image

// Update database with image name
```

The problem that i encounter is that after processing/saving the image, when its time to add this file name to the database, the value of `$saltdate` seems to have changed and i will get a file name in the database that doesnt exist.

**EDIT**

The value has changed in that the time increases from when i name the file to when i store the name in the DB.

How can i make sure that the value doesn't change once i establish it?

Comment: "the value of $saltdate seems to have changed" - changed in what way? It contains another seemingly valid value (i.e. a number which _might_ have been returned by date('U') but yet different from the value you expect)?

Comment: The return value of date('U') *(for which you might want to consider just using time())* is assigned by value, so it cannot change unless you modify it. Please provide more of the relevant code parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of error where a debugger comes in really handy. You can set a breakpoint in your code and then execute it step by step and inspect the state of variables et al.

You can use [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) as the server-side php module and e.g. [netbeans](http://netbeans.org) as a frontend/ide.
There's a short introduction for this combination at http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html

Answer (score 1):

Set it as a constant with define

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the `md5()` function, make sure that you are doing the same thing while retrieving the record back. Notice that you are using a date in your salt, make sure that things match up.

An easy way is to use `microtime` function instead.